# Where and how, to find the installer file after creating and adding set up project to a solution having a windows application?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005, installation, setup-project, windows

HI,
   I have a windows application in C#. I created and added a set up project to this solution. Then, built the solution. I refered to this link "http://www.codeproject.com/KB/install/SetupAndDeployment.aspx". I even added the shortcut of "**Primary output of my application**" to "User's Desktop" folder. But I am not able to find the installer file in Desktop, so that I can "double click" this installer file and install my Windows application. 
                      **KINDLY HELP ME WITH THE PROCEDURE THAT NEEDS TO BE FOLLOWED AFTER CREATING A SET UP PROJECT, ADDING IT TO A SOLUTION AND BUILDING THE SOLUTION. WHERE AND HOW TO FIND THE INSTALLER FILE. IS THERE ANYTHING THAT I AM MISSING.**